# How to make d3 donut chart's inner circle clickable?

Tags: d3.js

Since inner circle is blank, are there any way to select it? Or should I just append a transparent circle on it?

Comment: Try to make a fiddle with sample data then we could do something on it.

Comment: Yes add a transparent circle in the center and attach your click event to it.